# Python Pandas Filter By Row Contains (at any column)

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I'm really struggling to solve what seems like a simple problem. I'd like to filter a dataframe by rows, but the documentation "How do I filter specific rows from a DataFrame" is really dumb -- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html#min-tut-03-subset -- all examples involve first filtering by column.

I have a DataFrame with 36 columns per row and my values range between "Yes", "NaN", and "No". I'd like to select all rows that contain "No" in any given column. How do I truly filter by row?

Thanks so much!

Comment: kindly share sample data , with expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `any` to check for validity along the rows:

```
df[df.eq('No').any(1)]
```